# How to add header to react-native-router-flux tabbar?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm making simpe application using `react-native`, and its third party module `react-native-router-flux` for easy handling component navigator.

I want to add header component above `tabs` which showing my app name, and selected tab name. I tried several ways but I don't know where to put the header component code.

My top component code like this

```
<Router>
    <Scene key="root">    
        <Scene key="todoList" tabs tabBarStyle={{ top: 0, backgroundColor: '#ddd' }} tabBarIconContainerStyle={{ borderColor: '#000', borderWidth: 1}} initial>
            <Scene key="first" title="First" icon={TabIcon}>
                <Scene key="scarlet" component={TabComponent1} hideNavBar title="tab1" initial />
            </Scene>
            <Scene key="second" title="Second" icon={TabIcon}>
                <Scene key="scarlet2" component={TabComponent2} hideNavBar title="tab2" initial />
            </Scene>
            <Scene key="third" title="Third" icon={TabIcon}>
                <Scene key="scarlet3" component={TabComponent3} hideNavBar title="tab3" initial />
            </Scene>
        </Scene>
    </Scene>
</Router>
```

This actually look like

[image]

What I want to do is simply add header component above tabs, like

[image]

How to do that? Please give me a hint! where I put that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your own Header component, I think you should write one for yourself in a separate file and export/import it to the screens. The react-native itself is rendering the components one after the other in order (from up to the bottom). So if you are doing it this way you should place your imported Header component on the top inside the render() function.

The other way is using a third party module like the native-base (which has a Header component already definied).

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase

Comment: Yeah, I added custom header component to each of tab comp. Thanks!